# inset legend from top right corner / find size of swatchlegend bounding box

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

The question is the following. Using Inset, we can insert a legend in a Plot (in a Graphic, in general). E.g.

```
scale = 2
step=0.05

marker=Graphics[{FilledCurve@Line[{{0,0},{2,0},{2,1},{0,1},{0,0}}]},ImageSize->100];
legendlabels={"a"};
legend=SwatchLegend[{Directive[Blue,Opacity@0.5]},legendlabels,
LegendMarkers->ConstantArray[marker,1],
LegendMarkerSize->{{25,12.5}},LegendFunction->"Frame"];

epilog = {Inset[legend, Scaled[{1, 1} - step*{scale, 1}]]};

Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}], Epilog -> epilog, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 6 Pi}, {-1, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

By adjusting, in this case, the variables "scale" and "step" we can move the legend from the upper right corner towards the center of the plot.

However, if we knew the relative size of the axes of the rectangle bounding the legend, we could substitute it in "scale" and move the legend in such a way that it keeps the same distance from the x and y axes. Therefore...

*Question*

Is there a way to know the size of a legend constructed via SwatchLegend, LineLegend and the like?

**Answer**

Using Rasterize (Mathematica 10) we can get the size of the legend, and therefore do:

```
legend=SwatchLegend[{Directive[Blue,Opacity@0.5]},legendlabels,
LegendMarkers->ConstantArray[marker,1],
LegendMarkerSize->{{25,12.5}},LegendFunction->"Frame"]

Rasterize[legend, "RasterSize"]
(* {51,31} *)

epilog = {Inset[legend, Scaled[{1, 1} - 0.05*{51/31, 1}]]}
```

i.e. take "scale" = 51/31 and "step" = 0.05. The result of

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}], Epilog -> epilog, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 6 Pi}, {-1, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

is shown here (note "AspectRatio" = 1).

[image: plot with legend from upper right corner]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Mathematica 10, you can use the `"RasterSize"` element of [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html) to get the size of almost anything in pixels, like so:

```
legend = SwatchLegend[{Directive[Blue, Opacity@0.5]}, legendlabels, 
   LegendMarkers -> ConstantArray[marker, 1], 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {{25, 12.5}}, LegendFunction -> "Frame"];
Rasterize[legend, "RasterSize"]

(* {51, 31} *)
```